# What is the proper way to compare equality of two variables that could be NaN?

Tags: c++, equality, isnan

I found a bug in the codebase I'm working in where they check for equality of two doubles (`first, second`) using `first == second`, but these 2 variables could be `NaN`.

If both variables were `NaN` the equality would be `false`.

So my current solution is instead of

```
first == second
```

we use

```
(first == second || (std::isnan(first) && std::isnan(second))
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: lol, it might not have been a bug, just a programmer with more experience than you.

Comment: @user1095108 i mean it's not the intended behavior of that check in the codebase so it definitely was a bug

Comment: Do you want a “true” result if both items are NaNs or only if both items are the same NaN  (have the same sign and payload and are both signaling or both quiet)?

Comment: The whole point of NaN is that it's Not a Number. Code that compares two things that are supposed to be numbers should not expect that the comparison will yield `true` for two things that aren't numbers.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I think the former. This check was done in an `operator==` check and `first, second` here are attributes of the underlying class. For some reason, the original developer chose to initialize those variables to `std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()`

Comment: comparing floating point numbers using equality gives me the shivers.

Comment: @roulette01 yes, he was more experienced than you :) Can't you see? This is what happens if you let a skilled arithmetician go.

Answer (score 3):

First, evaluate that you actually *want* the condition to run if both values are NaN. NaN is a good indicator that things went terribly wrong, not a null or empty state. If the intention was to have two values that may or may not exist, you might consider changing them to `std::optional<double>` to make that clear. Otherwise, if you are certain, then what you've done is correct. There's no magic trick to making NaN comparisons work, and even if you did find a library that abstracted this away, it would still do exactly what you just did under the hood.

Comment: Some of those variables I'm checking are initialized to NaN for whatever reason, not sure why it was designe dthat way.

Comment: @roulette01 it sounds like your first step is to find out why it was designed that way

Comment: I disagree. While NaNs can be the result of arithmetic errors (division by zero etc.), programmers can also use them deliberately to indicate a null or empty state. Of course, doing such should be documented.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use an overly generic expression:

```
(first == second || (std::isnan(first) && std::isnan(second))
```

Use a named function to start with:

```
inline bool areFloatPointComparablyEquivelent(double lhs, double rhs)
{
      // Add a long very detailed explanation of why you need
      // This expression (in two years you will not be here and the
      // the next maintainer may own an axe and know where you live).

      // The exact reason or expression is not that important.
      // What is important (if not trivial, obvious) is a WHY.
      return result;
}
```

Now use this self documenting function wherever you need to do this test (even if it is only in one place).

Comment: Exactly, this is the way to go: NaNs are not evil. But they should be treated properly, if they are used for whatever reason, and the treatment chosen and the reasoning behind those choices should be documented.